# Android Design Templates

Tags: android, templates

I'm looking for XML Design templates for Android for last 2 days.
Please help me to get the stylish and fancy XML templates that i can reuse after customizing them.

Any response is appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give some more explanation about what you expect when you say "XML templates" ?

Comment: He's just looking for some premade, fancy XML layouts which he can customize and re-use.  It would be nice if we could find some of these but I'm pretty sure you'll have to create your fancy files yourself.

Comment: what kind of controls you want in the XML

Comment: Thanks for your response David, yes Veer you are right the templates are like sample of different predesigned  UI screens which anyone can reuse as per his requirement similar as web templates.

Comment: If you found anything, please share the link

Comment: Did you found anything @Shailendra?  
If you do, please let us know.

Comment: No @Salman there is no such thing given by google yet...

Comment: I know the question is about XML, but if anyone is using Jetpack Compose, check out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uidesigns.withsourcecode . I have added many UI designs along with source code and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at open source projects on Google Code or Github? I know this has helped me with UI re-use for creating action bars, etc (along with other patterns now found at http://developer.android.com/design). I know 'iosched' over at Google Code has helped me learn about layouts. As far as pre-defined templates, I do not know of a specific repository for this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you esilac for your information but its really not help me ,I need the XMl files for layout, themes, etc. samples which we can easily handle as per our requirements